# How to delete class from cache upon deleting from visual studio?

Tags: intersystems-iris

I have created new class in VSCode and upon saving it also saved in Cache DB but when I am deleting from VSCode it is not deleting from Cashe DB. How can I remove both class together?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a class in VSCode in fact you create a file that will stay in your repository.
When you load/compile this file into the connected IRIS server you get it on this server and you can call its methods and query it if it is a persistent class.

So when you delete the class in VSCode you delete the file in your repository, not the class in the IRIS server.

If you want to delete the class on the IRIS server you can do it with SQL if it is a persistent class:

```
DROP TABLE tablename_for_the_class
```

This will delete the class and its data.

You also can delete it manually from Class Explorer or SQL Explorer in the management portal.